# Find the integer value of a, b such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ax-\sqrt{x}+b}{x-4}=\frac{3}{4}$ without using the L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Find the integer value of $a$, $b$ such that  $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ax-\sqrt{x}+b}{x-4}=\frac{3}{4}$ without using the L'Hôpital's rule.
My work:

I multiplied with $\frac{ax+\sqrt{x}+b}{ax+\sqrt{x}+b}$, and obtained:

$=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(ax+b)^2-x}{(x-4)(ax+b+\sqrt{x})}$

$=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(a^2x^2+2abx+b^2-x)}{(x-4)(ax+b+\sqrt{x})}$

I factored $(x-4)$ from the numerator:

$(x-4)(a^2x+2ab-1+4a^2)+(b^2+8ab-4+16a^2)$

We have the first equation

$(b^2+8ab-4+16a^2)=0$

$=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(x-4)(a^2x+2ab-1+4a^2)}{(x-4)(ax+b+\sqrt{x})}$
$=\frac{4a^2+2ab-1+4a^2}{4a+b+2}=\frac{3}{4}$

So, the second equation is
$16a^2+8ab-4+16a^2=12a+3b+6$
$32a^2-12a+8ab-3b-10=0$
But I can't find the integer value of $a$, $b$.

Comment: Can you edit and use display maths (two dollar signs)

Comment: Hint:for the limit toexist numerator must tend to 0 when $x\to 4$

Comment: After your first step, the numerator does not condense to $(ax+b)^2$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I edited it, thanks!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I used that hint and obtained the first equation, and the second equation afterwards.

Comment: @user170231 Sorry I forgot to type the (-x), however the I typed the rest correctly.

Comment: @FiorellaSusanto I prepared my answer and collected all Your comments question in my answer. OK. I was not first for nice idea, but first for a complete checkable and therefore usable answer. Please rate and commend. I did not use quartics but names my methods and clear why it is that way correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $\sqrt x=y$, so that

$$\lim_{x\to4}\frac{ax-\sqrt x+b}{x-4}=\lim_{y\to2}\frac{ay^2-y+b}{y^2-4}=\frac34$$

We have

$$\frac{ay^2-y+b}{y^2-4}=a-\frac{y-4a-b}{(y-2)(y+2)}$$

For the limit to exist, $y=2$ must be a removable singularity, so $y-2$ must divide $y+4a+b$. We have

$$\frac{y-4a-b}{y-2}=1-\frac{4a+b-2}{y-2}$$

and the remainder should be such that $4a+b-2=0$. So,

$$\lim_{y\to2}\frac{ay^2-y+b}{y^2-4}=\lim_{y\to2}\left(a-\frac1{y+2}-\frac{4a+b-2}{(y+2)(y-2)}\right)=a-\frac14=\frac34$$

Then $a=1$ and $b=-2$.

Comment: Why is $\lim_{y \rightarrow 2} \frac{4a+b-2}{y-2}$ allowed? Isn't it equal to $\frac{4a+b-2}{0}=\infty$?

Comment: It would be unless the numerator is fixed and equal to $0$, in which case $\frac0{y-2}=0$.

Comment: I'm so sorry I still don't understand. Why is it $\frac{0}{y-2}$ and not $\frac{0}{2-2}=\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: The point is that in the limit, $y$ is approaching $2$, so for all intents and purposes, $y\neq2$, and $\frac0{y-2}=0$ for all $y\neq2$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$\frac{ax-\sqrt{x}+b}{x-4}
= a - \frac{1}{\sqrt x+2} + \frac{4a+b-2}{x-4}
$$
Then,  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ax-\sqrt{x}+b}{x-4}=\frac{3}{4}$ requires
$$a-\frac1{\sqrt4+2}= \frac34,\>\>\>\>\>4a+b-2=0$$
which yields $a=1$ and $b=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!
$$
\begin{cases}
b^2+8ab-4+16a^2=0\\
32a^2-12a+8ab-3b-10=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
gives two solutions$^*$

$a= -\frac{1}{4},b= -1$ discarded because there are fractions

$a= 1, b = -2$, the solution you were looking for.

---

$^*$

from the first equation $(b+4a)^2=4\to b+4a=\pm 2\to b=-4a\pm 2$

let $b=-4a+2$ and plug in the second equation

$32a^2-12a+8a(-4a+2)-3(-4a+2)-10=0\to 16 (a-1)=0\to a=1$

and $b = -2$

the other solution $b=-4a-2$ leads to the fractions.

Comment: I didn't think about using the $(a+b)^2$ form to solve the equation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$(2-\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})=4-x$ is a great start for partial fraction decomposition.

$a+\frac{1}{ 2 + \sqrt{x}}+\frac{-2 + 4 a + b}{-2 + \sqrt{x}}=\frac{a(x-4)+B(2-\sqrt{x})+C}{x-4}$

with $B=-1$ and $C=-2+4a+b$.

Take into account that

$$\frac{a x- \sqrt{x} + b}{x - 4}=a-\frac{1}{ 2 + \sqrt{x}}+\frac{-2 + 4 a +b}{-2 + \sqrt{x}}$$

This denominator is not compensable anymore by $\sqrt{x}$ in the nominator. So the nominators have to be zero for the existence of the limit.

The last summand has to be eliminated for a limit to exist!

$$\frac{4 a + b-2}{\sqrt{x}-2}$$

That can only the satisfied once for $-2$  or for $y$ but not for both to not singular.

We have $\frac{3}{4}=a-\frac{1}{4}$ and $4a+b=2$ so that $a=1$ so $b=-2$.

The back substition show we only have reals and therefore only are in need of the positive solution at $x=4$. The calculation remains valid.

The solution is for fitting to the given value/limit:

$$\frac{ x - \sqrt{x} -2}{x - 4}$$.

At $x=4$ the nominator has a zero $ 4 - \sqrt{4} -2=0$ that compensates for the zero of the polynomial of first order in $x$ in the denominator. The nominator is not a polynomial in $x$ but a sum of a polynomial and a second order root. Both a steady and differentiable in the singularity of the denominator.

A plot shows the singularity is gone:

The solution is $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x=0$ and $1$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ at $x=4 and this is no limit!$.

[image]

The solution process is substition of the root. Then partial fraction decompostion and the fitting the parameters of the given functions to the singularity at $x=4$. Finally we analysed the function and displayed it after resubstitution.

We needed a factor in addition to match the given limit. The pair $(a,b)=(1,-2)$ is unique.